# Complement of union

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $T=[0,5]$ be the space in which the sets $A,B$ "live" in.

So if $A=(1,2)$ then $A^c=[0,1]\cup [2,5]$ right?

If $B=(3,4)$ then $A\cup B=(1,2)\cup (3,4)$

And then $(A\cup B)^c=[0,1]\cup[2,3]\cup[4,5]$,right?

Comment: Yep, those are correct!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right. That is precisely what it should be.